# Node.js v10.16.0 implementation of AES 256 CTR decryption using PHP

Tags: php, node.js, aes

The key that I have to use for decryption is a 80 characters long string. 
I can't figure out the length of iv needed for that kind of key in the Node.js implementation.

PHP snippet that I'm trying to convert to Node.js:

```
protected function Decryption($theData, $theKey) {
 $method = 'aes-256-ctr';
 $nonceSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
 $nonce = mb_substr($theData, 0, $nonceSize, '8bit');
 $ciphertext = mb_substr($theData, $nonceSize, null, '8bit');
 $plaintext = openssl_decrypt( $ciphertext, $method, $theKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $nonce);
 return json_decode($plaintext);
}
```

Node.js implementation, throwing Invalid IV length error:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
const decipher  = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', theKey, nonce);
let plainText = decipher.update(theData, 'base64', 'utf8');
plainText += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log(plainText);
```

This could be solved by using different length of key but in this case I need to use 80 characters.

EDIT
After updating to use the fix from [Getting error of Invalid IV Length while using aes-256-cbc for encryption in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485408/getting-error-of-invalid-iv-length-while-using-aes-256-cbc-for-encryption-in-nod) , I'm getting Invalid key length error with this code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var iv = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16))
var nonce = iv.toString('hex').slice(0, 16);
const decipher  = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', theKey, nonce);
let plainText = decipher.update(theData, 'base64', 'utf8');
plainText += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log(plainText);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what should be done and how. My guess - the nonce/iv is the shorter one, and it's 16 bytes now. So, the solution is to append 64 bytes with the value of 0x00 on the right side of it, which will make it 80, but 64 are going to be 0x00? Thank you for your quick reply and please let me know if my understanding of it is correct.

Comment: I can see why, I wrote it in a bad way, let me clarify - the key that I have to use is 80 characters, not 80 bits. And it doesn't work with the IV size of 16 bytes. (the node.js implementation that I posted is throwing 'Invalid IV length at new Decipheriv'. I'm trying to make it work with the 80 characters key that was provided to me and I'm having this problem). I'm trying to rewrite PHP implementation to Node.js and apparently I'm missing something that is causing this problem.

Comment: This is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/42485408/1820553

Comment: Unfortunately fix from this issue is not helping me - I added edited my question with code snippet with the fix as a point of reference, because maybe it has to be implemented differently.